# changing device and vendor id of Digispark Digikey

Tags: linux, usb, raspberry-pi, arduino, vendor-id

i saw a tutorial on [null-byte](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/hack-macos-with-digispark-ducky-script-payloads-0198555/) on how to change the vendor id of a Digikey so that it could be programmed on macOS.

I'm on mac so I'm using my raspberry pi to program the usb. the tutorial said to go to `.arduino15/packages/digistump/hardware/avr/1.6.7/libraries/DigisparkKeyboard/usbconfig.h` to change the ID.

the default vendor ID is `#define USB_CFG_VENDOR_ID 0xc0, 0x16` and I changed it to `#define USB_CFG_VENDOR_ID 0xac, 0x05`. unfortunately my mac still could not connect to the usb.

I did an `lsusb` to check for connected devices and found that it still had the default Digikey vendor code: `Bus 001 Device 030: ID 16d0:0753 MCS Digistump DigiSpark`. there are multiple `usbconfig.h` files so i changed all of them to match what the tutorial said but none of them have made any difference.

TL;DR: does anyone know how I can change the vendor ID of a Digispark USB?